# Nested Closures in Swift 2.1

Tags: ios, ios9, ios9.1, swift2

**I want to clear about Nested Closures in Swift 2.1**

Here I declare a nested closure,

```
  typealias nestedDownload = (FirstItem: String!)-> (SencondItem: String!)->Void
```

Then I use this `nestedDownload` closure as a parameter of the following function and  try to complete the compliletion parameter value in function  like as

```
func nestedDownloadCheck(compliletion:nestedDownload){

        compliletion(FirstItem: "firstItem")
}
```

But this says the error, "**Expression resolves to an unused function**"

Also , when I call `nestedDownloadCheck()` from `ViewDidLoad()` method by tring to fill the body of the compilation

```
self.nestedDownloadCheck { (FirstString) -> (SecondString: String!) -> Void in
            func OptionalFunction(var string:String)->Void{


            }
            return OptionalFunction("response")
        }
```

This says the compilation error "**Cannot convert return expression of type 'Void'(aka'()') to return Type '(SecondString: String!) -> Void'** "

I can't find out how I exactly use the nested closure in this way .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return the actual `OptionalFunction`, not invoke it with `"response"` and return that value. **And** you have to use `String!` in the definition:

```
nestedDownloadCheck { (FirstString) -> (SecondString: String!) -> Void in
    func OptionalFunction(inputString:String!) -> Void {

    }
    return OptionalFunction
}
```

Note that functions should start with a lower case letter: `optionalFunction`.

What your code does is

- define a function called `OptionalFunction`
- call that function with `"response"` as parameter
- return the value returned by that invocation (`Void`)

> The compiler therefore correctly tells you that `Void` is no convertible to the expected return value of `(SecondString: String!) -> Void`

What you are finally missing is to invoke the actual returned function like so:

```
func nestedDownloadCheck(compliletion:nestedDownload){
    compliletion(FirstItem: "firstItem")(SencondItem: "secondItem")
}
```