# Passing closure to another closure

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift programing development. I want to know to how to pass a closure to another closure.

Is there any difference between closure in swift and blocks in objective.

Comment: You may declare variable of function type and do with this variable whatever you want.

Comment: Closure is replacement to the blocks, it is not exactly same. You can refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591777/nested-closures-in-swift-2-1

Answer (score 2):

#### How to pass a closure to a closure?

A closure can be seen as just any other (non-closure) type. This means you can construct a closure where the argument of the closure describes another closure type.

E.g.

```
let sendMeAClosure: ((Int) -> String) -> () = {
    print($0(42)) /* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- argument of sendMeAClosure
                                      is a closure itself        */
}

let myClosure: (Int) -> String = {
    return "The answer is \($0)."
}

sendMeAClosure(myClosure) // The answer is 42
```

Note that functions in Swift are just a special type of closure, so you might as well supply a function reference (which has a signature matching the argument type) to `sendMeAClosure` above.

```
/* sendMeAClosure as above */

func myFunc(arg: Int) -> String {
    return "The answer is \(arg)."
}

sendMeAClosure(myFunc) // The answer is 42
```

#### Is there any difference between closure in swift and blocks in objective?

For your 2nd question, refer to the following Q&A

- [Difference between block (Objective C) and closure (Swift) in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374792/difference-between-block-objective-c-and-closure-swift-in-ios)